# What's the different between ` and ' in programming, such as MySQL and shells

Tags: mysql, shell, character

phpMySQL use backticks ` to surround column names, and I've just see people use backticks in shell scripts.

Is that the same if they use ' ?

Comment: In shells that support it, such as Bash, it is preferable to use `$()` in place of backticks. You don't have to do as much special character escaping and you can easily nest commands: `var="terminal [ $(ps h -p $(pgrep -f "getty.*tty4")) ] tty4"`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In `MySQL`, backticks could be used to enclose table and column names which are reserved words, like this:

```
SELECT  *
FROM    `table`
```

Single quotes just denote a string constant:

```
SELECT  *
FROM    `table`
WHERE   `name` = 'test'
```

In shells, backticks let you use the output of one command as an argument to another command:

```
echo `date`
```

will execute `date` and use its output as an argument to `echo`.

Single quotes let you use whitespaces, dollar signs and backslashes inside the arguments:

```
echo '$HOSTNAME'
```

will output the string `$HOSTNAME` as it is,

```
echo $HOSTNAME
echo "$HOSTNAME"
```

both will output the value of the environment variable `HOSTNAME`.

Answer (score 0):

In shell, a pair of backticks will be replaced by the (stdout) output of the command they enclose.

```
X=`expr 3 \* 2 + 4` # expr evaluate arithmatic expressions. man expr for details.
echo “$X”
```